# Save canvas img to server folder

Tags: image, canvas, save

```
   $("#downloadPdf").click(function () {
    $(".img-indicator").hide();
    html2canvas($("#frame"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var image = canvas.toDataURL(
                    'image/png');

                    image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');



            $("#generatedImg").val(image);
            window.open(image);
        }
    });
});
```

I want to save this image to folder that is located on a server,
and I want to save that image with specific file name too.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript/jQuery run on the client side and cannot access the server folders. You need to create a web page on your server that will receive the file from your JavaScript/jQuery and saves it in the folder. Then you can call this page from your JavaScript/jQuery using `$.ajax`.